# Android Window Background Landscape appear in low resolution

Tags: android, image, background, themes, galaxy

Device: Samsung Galaxy Tab

I followed this guide: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/window-bg-speed.html

I put the background image in a theme to improve performance and i works really good in portrait orientation.

Theme:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.xxxx" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_xxxx</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I attach the theme in the Manifest file to the activity.

```
    <activity android:name=".main" 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:theme="@style/Theme.xxxx">
```

In drawable directory i create the file background_xxxx.xml:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/background_image"
    android:tileMode="disabled" />
```

In drawable-hdpi directory i put my image 600x1024 px called background_image.png

In drawable-large-land directory i put my image 1024x600 px called background_image.png for the landscape orientation

When i start my app in portrait orientation, i see it with the background image in hight definition, but if i rotate it i see the image put in drawable-large-land directory put in low resolution.

Where do I have to put the landscape image to see it in hight resolution?

Thanks.

Comment: I found the answer: put the background image in res/drawable-large-land-hdpi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fault is little. See this in your question:

> In **drawable-large-land** directory i put my image 1024x600 px called background_image.png for the landscape orientation

You have to use `drawable-land-hdpi` folder to put images

Comment: Eclipse get me this error: invalid resource directory name drawable-hdpi-land

Comment: for large screen, put the background image in res/drawable-large-land-hdpi

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in drawable-mdpi first and then drawable-ldpi if first one dont work.
This hit will work :)